# Нехай я заплачу / хай пише: чому є використання наказового способу 1 і 3 ос. одн.?

Tags: діалектизми, наказовий-спосіб

У Шевченка читаю ("До Основ’яненка"):

Утни, батьку, орле сизий!

Нехай я заплачу,

Нехай свою Україну

Я ще раз побачу.

Знаю, що 1 особи однини у наказовому способі нема. Тому зараз же вживати таку конструкцію, яка є у посланні, не нормативно. Тоді чим зумовлено те, що Т. Г. Шевченко використовував таку конструкцію? Які зміни могли відбутися? Чи збереглась така конструкція у діалектах?

Аналогічно цікавить і 3 ос одн. Наприклад, “хай пише!”

Comment: можна не тільки приймати відповіді, а й голосувати стрілочкою вгору, якщо вони вам подобаються. так користувач отримає ще більше рейтинґу і ще більше захоче відповідати на питання далі.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Роздуми*</sup>

Тямка *не нормативно* стосує лише 1 особи однини, бо для 3 особи є правило.

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 400.](http://sum.in.ua/s/nekhaj)

> **НЕХА́Й**, *розмовне* **НЕХ**.
>
> **1.** *частка*, *у сполученні* з *дієсловом* *3 особи однини* або *множини* теперішнього або майбутнього *чололовічого роду* Уживається для утворення аналітичної форми наказового способу 3 особи дієслова, що виражає:
>
> **а)** наказ, спонукання.
>
> *— Іди до батьків, кланяйся їм та скажи, нехай йдуть до мене жити* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1950, 303); *— Бригадою нехай командує Сашко… Слухайте Миколу Щорса* (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 209); *— Ну, братця, над мертвим стояти ніколи. Нехай, лишень, візьмуть котрі, однесуть тіло додому* (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 346); *— Я піду в економію працювати. Не велике щастя покину у вас, нех воно горить!* (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 109);
>
> **б)** дозвіл, згоду, припущення.
>
> *— Не пущу ж я тебе, голубчику мій милий, соколе мій ясний!.. Нехай і мене беруть із тобою…* (Гнат Хоткевич, I, 1966, 142); *— Кажуть, в місті холера, — сказав Буренкін. — Нехай собі говорять! — машинально відповів Мічурін* (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 433);
>
> **в)** побажання, заклик.
>
> *— Як помер наш батько, — нехай йому земля пером! — оставив нам дев'ять пар волів* (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 37); *В квітках всі улиці кричать: нехай, нехай живе свобода!* (Павло Тичина, I, 1957, 71);

Існує і чинниь — 2015 — правопис

> #### [§ 33. Частки](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par33B)
>
> а) частки **хай**, **неха́й**, за допомогою яких утворюються форми третьої особи однини й множини наказового способу: *Хай живе мир між народами! Нехай міцніють дружні відносини між: країнами!*

<sup>*Цїкаво, що: 

а) нема в УП 1892, а 1928 — лиш згадка: „Нехай ні жар, ні холод не спинить вас.“ (Ів. Франко); 

б) тїльки 3 особи однини чи множини; а [рада](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/nakazovyj-sposib) від Антоненка-Давидовича включає 1 особи однини.*</sup>

---

Так, вжив слова наразї не широкий. Гадаю, одна з основних причин (так би мовити спрощеннь) наразї є *викання* замість [мовлення](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96) *пан* [чи](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q="%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD") *панї*, [наприклад](//google.com.ua/search?q=niech+pani) польська досї широко [вживає](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/niech) так, *[niech](http://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=8300&id_znaczenia=0)* + …:

> Форма наказового 3 особи однини чи множини:
>
> *Niech moc będzie z tobą!
>
>   Niech cię Bóg błogosławi.*
>
> ---
>
> Форма наказового 1 особи однини:
>
> *Niech no pomyślę…
>
>   Niech zgadnę… ty jesteś John?*

Отже може цїлком десь зберегтися в західних краях.